# Delphi exceptions not letting me see local variables

Tags: delphi

When debugging in Delphi, an exception will correctly tell me the line of code causing the fault, but I cannot get access to any local variables.  Is this a limitation in the debugger?  Or am I missing something simple?  At present, I have to mirror all local variables to a global on the line before the fault, recompile the program and hope to be able to repeat the same exception.

For example

```
MyArray[I]:=Foo(...);
```

If `I` is out of bounds (with bounds checking turned on), I cannot see what the variable `I` is, unless I mirrored it to a globally scoped debug variable on the previous line.

Or if I have

```
MyInteger:=Trunc(MyFloat),
```

and `MyFloat` is `6.1E+17`, I have no idea what it's value is.

Comment: This is a known limitation of the debugger. There's not much you can do.

Comment: I'm new here (first post).  I can't seem to find "question answered", yet I've seen other say "remember to mark the question answered."  How do I do that?

Comment: As I recall, when I've encountered this limitation, Robert, I've explicitly set a breakpoint on the line causing the problem (assuming the problem is reproducbable) so that I can get access to the local variables just before the exception.  Or, I've surrounded the local code with a try...except and put a line in the except block on which I could set a break point.

Comment: The problem with setting a break point is that you may be in a loop such as
   "for I:=0 to Length(Array) do begin"

it won't be until the last iteration of the array that you realize you went one too far.

Comment: @Robert: Delphi allows conditional breakpoints.  Even though you set a breakpoint inside the loop you can add a condition like "i = 100".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the values of local variables when you select the proper line in the call stack window. It is usually one or two lines before the exception is raised.

I don't have the exact version at hand when this has been implemented, but it is definitely one of the newer versions.

Comment: I can confirm D7 cannot, but D2007 can show the values in local variables window (not in watches window though) when double clicked on the appropriate line in call stack.

Comment: I verified this works in XE3.  I don't why there are two stacks for each procedure or function in the stack trace, but one of the two gives wildly inaccurate results, but the other gives correct results.  I haven't tried any real debugging yet (just deliberate exceptions), but I assume 99% of the time, it will be obvious which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is caused by the compiler as far as I know. The optimization feature of the compiler acts like a garbage collector, it frees the variables declared within a function when not used any more.

To overcome the problem, write a exception handler and make a fake use of the variable within the exception catch block.